# Convert SQL to JPQL Spring boot

Tags: sql, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa, jpql

I'm wondering how to convert this query to JPQL:

```
SELECT t.id, t.title ,
       (select count(l.id) from topic_like l where t.id = l.topic_id) as countt
from topics t;
```

[image]

Comment: You need to show the entities. How did you map the association between `topics` and `topic_like`?

Comment: Thanks Davide, I attached the entities.

Comment: Please, in the future try not to past code as an image.

Comment: what did you try?
What was not working? did you face any problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subqueries in the select and where clauses will work.
You can write the same query as:

```
select t, (select count(l.id) from TopicLikeJpa l where l.topic.id = t.id)
from TopicJpa t
```

you can replace `select t` with `select t.id, t.name` if you don't want to load the whole entity.

But I think you can rewrite the same query without subqueries as

```
select t, count(l)
from TopicJpa t
         left join t.topicLikeJpa l
group by t.id
```

or

```
select t.id, t.title, count(l)
from TopicJpa t
         left join t.topicLikeJpa l
group by t.id, t.title
```

Comment: Thanks @Davide D'Alto, I'm wondering if I want to load specific columns, Do I need to create a class that has what I need? And use (SELECT NEW classPath.ClassName) At beginning of the query?

Comment: If you want. You can also return a `List<Object[]>` instead of a class. I mention it here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72675969/jpa-queries-aggregate-function-count-with-two-tables/72676336#72676336

Comment: As a SQL its works, but when i use the entity I've got some issues.
@Query("SELECT p,count(k.id) as likes FROM TopicJpa p LEFT JOIN TopicLikeJpa k GROUP BY p ORDER BY COUNT(likes)")
    Page<TopicJpa> getAllTopicsWithLikeCountsSort(Pageable pageable);

Comment: What kind of error do you have?

Comment: The query is not correct, check my answer. That's not how you do a join in HQL

Comment: You can find many examples in [the documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/6.1/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#hql-join)